# In Flutter/dart how do i stop whatever media is playing on a phone?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am very new to Flutter and Dart, so this might just be very basic. I´m searching for a way to stop whatever media is playing on a Phone. Just like when you´re listening to Music on Spotify and, for example, start a Youtube video or get a call, the music pauses.

Like i said, i am not particulary experienced with Flutter, but i have tried two packages called "audioplayers" ('package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';) and "Flutter_Audio_Player" ('package:flutter_audio_player/flutter_audio_player.dart';), both of witch i haven´t had any success with.
These packages seem to be more intended to build something like an actual music-player, according to the information, that i found online.
Here is the code, witch i have been testing: but it doesn´t actually stop any media running on my phone:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  void _pauseAudio() {
    audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Audio Player'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Press the button to pause the audio'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _pauseAudio,
        tooltip: 'Pause',
        child: Icon(Icons.pause),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe i´m missing something obvious here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use await

```
void _pauseAudio() {
await audioPlayer.pause();
}
```